# Regex on multiple files

Tags: regular-expression

Very new to regex and have a directory of files that I would like run this regex on but don't know how. help would be great.

This is the regex:

```
(?<=#).*
```

Comment: `grep '(?<=#).*' /path/to/files/*`

Comment: @DopeGhoti That looks like a Perl lookaround, and would need `-P`

Comment: Do you have an example or examples of what it should match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex pattern `(?<=#).*` is a zero width positive look-behind pattern that requires PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) supported `grep` to be implemented. If your `grep` supports `-P` option then you can do it.

Seeing the pattern, i think you might also need `-o` option to get only the matched portion, as `(?<=#)` makes sure there is a `#` before the desired portion `.*`.

So you can do recursive `grep` (`-r`):

```
grep -rPo '(?<=#).*' /directory
```

Comment: now i want to insert text at the start of the lines I'm finding with this regex #(?<=#).*

Comment: @fuzzled please ask it as a new question with some examples..

Comment: You could also use `pcregrep` instead.  It supports `-r` and `-o` just like grep.  `man grep` on my box warns that `-P` is "highly experimental".

Comment: @Wildcard yeah but `pcregrep` is not available by default on any distro i am aware of and regarding that warning..it is a long story..  :)

Comment: Fair enough.  I do think your answer is best but I thought it should at least be noted (in the comments) that `pcregrep` exists.  :)